# methods returns the last return only all the time in angular 6 method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe((user: User) => {
      this.user = user;
      if (this.user.id) {
        return of(true); //line 5
      } else {
        if (localStorage.getItem(CommonConstants.TOKEN)) {
          this.loginService.getUserDetails().subscribe((res: User) => {
            this.user = res;
            this.data.changeMessage(res);
            if (this.user.id) {
              return of(true); //line 12
            } else {
              return of(false); //line 14
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
    return of(true); //line 20
  }
```

Here none of my return at line 5, 12, 14 is not returning even though the condition met. It always returns the line 20 the last return value.
  Why this strange behavior ?

environment :

**angular 6**

Comment: You're not thinking 'reactively' enough. If you're going to return an observable, then combine several observables together, perhaps map to a boolean as a last step in order to return a Observable<boolean>.  Remove the subscribe call, leave it to your clients to subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the observable as well

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.data.currentMessage.subscribe((user: User) => {
      this.user = user;
      if (this.user.id) {
        return of(true); //line 5
      } else {
        if (localStorage.getItem(CommonConstants.TOKEN)) {
          this.loginService.getUserDetails().subscribe((res: User) => {
            this.user = res;
            this.data.changeMessage(res);
            if (this.user.id) {
              return of(true); //line 12
            } else {
              return of(false); //line 14
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
    return of(true); //line 20
  }
```

Comment: [ts]
Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the code in question is **asynchronous**. This means that, although line 20 is the last line in your function, it's actually one of the first to be executed.

Instead of subscribe, I would suggest using functions like `map`, or `flatMap` here as well, which allow you to transform the `Observable`.

Try something like this:

```
  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.data.currentMessage.pipe(
      flatMap((user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
        if (this.user.id) {
          return of(true); //line 5
        } else if (localStorage.getItem(CommonConstants.TOKEN)) {
          return this.loginService.getUserDetails()
        }
      }),

      map((res: User) => {
        this.user = res;
        this.data.changeMessage(res);
        return this.user.id;
      })
    );
  }
```